# Bootstrap columns not working like how I expect?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want a master_page with a top, left, and right section. I am having issues with the left and right section... The left is flush with the screen like how i want, the right section is not at all.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <aside>This is the left content</aside>
      <ul>
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
        <li>Test 5</li>
        <li>Test 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="mainContent" runat="server">
        <p>Default Main Content</p>
      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <aside>Right Content</aside>
      <ul>
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
        <li>Test 5</li>
        <li>Test 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

In this image you can see there is still tons of space.

If I try to increase the column sizes more, the right content just goes down below because 4 + 4 + 4 is bigger than 12... which makes sense, but this should work, no???

Comment: The green squiggly line under my divs say it can't be nested in HTML but it is still working as expected except this grid issue?

Comment: What is the intended result? That the text in the right-hand column is flush-up against the right-hand edge of the viewport? Because your right-hand column currently takes up the entire right-hand third of the screen; change the background colour to see this.

Comment: The intended result is for it just to expand across the entire page when I have a fullscreen google chrome window up on the web page. Does it have to do with it just making it smaller for some reason? Because my viewport is smaller? I basically just want the FINAL result to be like two side nav bars extending the length of the screen with them both flush at the left and the right edges of the browser. With content in the middle that changes. I can make the content int he middle change but on my browser it doesn't seem flush to the sides on the right

Comment: You already have that :) It just looks as though the right-hand column doesn't extent all the way to the right, because the content (text) is flush up against the left-hand side of the right column. All three columns are flush up against one another, and do indeed occupy one-third of the `width` each (totalling the full `width` of the page, regardless of how wide your browser is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the right result.
Because you didn't set the text to be displayed in right side.
You can verify if it is in right place, by giving background color.

And the code must be like this

```
<aside class="float-right">
  <ul>...</ul>
</aside>
```